# Application not getting render due to pending download of js files in head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I need to load set of js in header. Below is my header element:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://saswdswddx.cloudfront.net/ClientLibs.js"/>
</head>
```

which ultimately generates below head section:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/89cc9bacc8f01db1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/211850746383fd35.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/b30b4a28e94073b3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/bc0c3159d13ffdaf.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/080d763d10e18196.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/84df93ace8f5ef4d.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/e7b23f7c66091e21.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/1d4c3d5cded23cb2.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/6f8353875d2eab13.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/22635695f659cee6.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/f645699f959874ea.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/52bf1c32f66e3366.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/7c14d48ac546cfab.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/3c2c0190729a5de6.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/905fab7bd45ffd32.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/aa6c83d100400291.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/1583adf5ca69f94b.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/7351efd5ad3a8219.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/d2a3be708cf0ecb2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/09511a5f22cca316.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/51a8a84831926cab.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/cebd04bf55acaf98.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/8f7a98b8524699fa.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/c765ce94b008b43a.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/d411591679fc777a.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/fd4e563878f699ca.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/a7aa4ab396dc2c06.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/74bfd02e310d0c96.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/777512d78b46f09a.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/9a00d70cd5a8f544.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/05da1be4803bfe93.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/3d3ff45927792b85.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/34f252296c86892b.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/6598462041ef9c9f.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/da39a3ee5e6b4b0d.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/4fb6b6291f77a814.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/e555a7200b70dcee.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/0fd5ba39ae8af05a.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/e64a562a726c1b03.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/296c14c415f75a7a.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/fe68b7820bc0cf4f.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/d836af899190a3f7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/05e03b1ae258b4cd.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/82de18bac08fa17f.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/46f426bcfc9dd89c.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/2046534748dde247.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/6e94559c187d5d00.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/74531b771786a1fd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/39ffcb4194a365fc.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/1b05d38fb2515b7c.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/2e91a32ab37b51d5.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/4dc09203c5082946.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/8ac01bbb7f05e0a9.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/ed192084e9139b54.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/ab612c7a907116a6.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/8deedebe93f06b91.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/6012e3e21c48364e.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/8486fc770633b5d7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/27525a908ad9afa6.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/e1c04b332299c91a.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/6048e657d7aa5b54.min.css"><script src="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/685b3fc65211ee22.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://xxxxfffdfdfdfd.cloudfront.net/7ec73ef718990b40.min.css">
  </head>
```

Also, in my body section the spa starts with init() method, which contains variable and component which are available is above js files in head section.
Now unless and until all my js files will get load, my application wont render.
So everytime i am getting error, undefined variable.
I want init mehod in body must call only after all js files in head section get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browsers you're targetting, you can or can not use the [`async`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_script_async.asp) keyword.

The solution I personally use in production is to move all the script tags to the bottom of the `<body>` element, and order them in the order of dependency.

So you move the script from the CDN to the bottom of the `<body>` tag,
and you put the script with the `init()` method *after* it.

Example:

I have two scripts. `script1` depends on `script2`, so it needs to be loaded after it.
Here's what I'd do:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Some HTML here...
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
    <script src="script1.js></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you could manually load the scripts in whatever order you want using AJAX, but that would be needlessly complicated.

Comment: actually these script names are dynamically generated, so i need to put them to CDN. Also order of loading these script matters. Now i got stuck, so need urgent help for this problem i.e how to load script in order and whithout loading them i dont want to move further

Comment: You can nudge the browser towards what order you want it to execute the scripts. It's done via the order of the `<script>` tags.